Конструктор работает некорректно (или не работает вовсе)
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include "Car.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    Car Car1("1", 1000, 400, 2000);
    Car1.Print();

}

Программа запускается, но вместо нужных параметров на месте заданных параметров нули (вместо строки пустота).
Не могу понять причину. Помогите пожалуйста.
Вывод:
Vehicle Object Created
Car Object Created
Name:
Horse Power: 0
Gas Tank Capacity: 0
Mass of the car: 0
Maximum Speed: -2.14748e+09
Car Object Deleted
Vehicle object Deleted

Vehicle.h:
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Vehicle
{
    std::string   name;
    float         horsePower;
    float         gasTank;
    float         mass;

public:

    std::string   GetName();
    float         GetHP();
    float         GetGT();
    float         GetMass();

    virtual void Print();

    Vehicle(std::string n, float hp, float gas, float mass);
    Vehicle();

    ~Vehicle();
};

Vehicle.cpp:
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string Vehicle::GetName()
{
    return this->name;
}

float Vehicle::GetHP()
{
    return this->horsePower;
}

float Vehicle::GetGT()
{
    return this->gasTank;
}

float Vehicle::GetMass()
{
    return this->mass;
}

void Vehicle::Print()
{
    std::cout   << "Name: "                << this->GetName()   << std::endl;
    std::cout   << "Horse Power: "         << this->GetHP()     << std::endl;
    std::cout   << "Gas Tank Capacity: "   << this->GetGT()     << std::endl;
}


Vehicle::Vehicle(std::string n, float hp, float gt, float m)
{
    name         = n;
    horsePower   = hp;
    gasTank      = gt;
    mass         = m;
    std::cout << "Vehicle Object Created" << std::endl;
}

Vehicle::Vehicle() 
{ 
    name         = "";
    horsePower   = 0;
    gasTank      = 0;
    mass         = 0;
    std::cout << "Vehicle Object Created" << std::endl;
}

Vehicle::~Vehicle()
{
    std::cout << "Vehicle object Deleted" << std::endl;
}

Car.h:
#pragma once
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include <string>

class Car : public Vehicle
{
    std::string   name;
    float         horsePower;
    float         gasTank;
    float         mass;
    float         maxSpeed;

public:

    float   CalcMaxSpeed();

    void Print() override;

    //Constructor
    Car();
    Car(std::string n, float hp, float gt, float m);

    //Destructor
    ~Car();
};

Car.cpp:
#include "Car.h"
#include <iostream>

float Car::CalcMaxSpeed()
{
    int maxSpeed = this->GetHP() / this->GetMass() * 100;
    return maxSpeed;
}

void Car::Print()
{
    std::cout << "Name: "                << this->GetName()        << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Horse Power: "         << this->GetHP()          << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Gas Tank Capacity: "   << this->GetGT()          << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Mass of the car: "     << this->GetMass()        << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Maximum Speed: "       << this->CalcMaxSpeed()   << std::endl;
}

Car::Car()
{
    std::cout << "Car Object Created" << std::endl;
}

Car::Car(std::string n, float hp, float gt, float m)
{
    this->name         = n; 
    this->horsePower   = hp;
    this->gasTank      = gt;
    this->mass         = m;
    std::cout << "Car Object Created" << std::endl;
}

Car::~Car()
{
    std::cout << "Car Object Deleted" << std::endl;
}


А зачем вы дублируете в потомке
std::string   name;
float         horsePower;
float         gasTank;
float         mass;

Результат: вы заполняете эти члены потомка, но в Print используете НЕвиртуальные функции предка, так что они возвращают данные из предка, вами не заполненные...
Попробуйте убрать их из потомка, в предке объявить как protected, а конструктор записать так:
Car::Car(std::string n, float hp, float gt, float m)
    :Vehicle(n,hp,gt,m){}

Впрочем, это protected не сильно и надо, раз вы обращаетесь к ним через открытый интерфейс Vehicle.

Но ведь поля не наследуются?
Что тогда делать?

С чего вы так решили?... А, ну да, сделайте их protected.

Но можно protected и не делать, вы же к ним не обращаетесь напрямую. И спасибо здесь имеет вид щелчка мышкой на треугольнике вверх слева от ответа; большое спасибо — щелчок на "птичке" там же...

Если не делаю protected, вылезают ошибки доступа, мол "Невозможно обратиться к private члену, определенному в классе Vehicle

Где? Вы же к ним напрямую не обращаетесь, только в (неправильно написанном) конструкторе; я показал, как написать конструктор правильно.
